# Why do some results show up in Google Maps but not in Places API results?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

Ok, so when I search for "Dobry" on Google Maps I get this result:   http://maps.google.de/maps/place?q=dobry&hl=de&cid=15804306880695571087

But when I try to retrieve that same restaurant from the Places API,   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=48.1321091,11.366&radius=500&types=establishment&sensor=false&name=Dobry&key=ABCDEF1234, I get `ZERO_RESULTS`.

How can I retrieve the `id` (not cid) Tag of that establishment? And why do the results differ? The lat/long location should be right. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: same issue here...If I call https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=RESTAURANTNAME&key=APIKEY in Gmaps there are two restaurants. The places API only returns one..

Answer (score 0):

The search box uses the [Query Autocomplete](http://%20https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/query) endpoint, it will give the same result, use the location parameter to bias the results