# difference between (html) google maps search results and maps/places api calls (fewer results)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I want to get restaurants in German cities to embed and process in a web page. I identify those cities through lat/long and radius (for approximation).

When doing an online search on google maps, I see 100s of results.

[google maps restaurant search duesseldorf](https://www.google.de/maps/search/restaurant+d%C3%BCsseldorf/@51.2277411,6.7734556,15z/data=!3m1!4b1)

My attempt at an implementation (mostly based on samples found here) only returns a lot less results (you can copy to .html page). I also tried adding API key, which I removed for here.

(I think where it says "request" is the interesting for the search results.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map_canvas {
            height: 100%;
        }

        #search-panel {
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -180px;
            width: 350px;
            z-index: 5;
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #999;
        }

        #target {
            width: 345px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var aDone = false;
        var bDone = false;
        function initializea() {
            aDone = true;
            if (aDone && bDone)
                initialize();
        }
        function initializeb() {
            bDone = true;
            if (aDone && bDone)
                initialize();
        }
        function initialize() {
            {
                // cologne
                var plat = 50.9344595;
                var plong = 6.9476285;
                // duesseldorf
                plat = 51.2277411;
                plong = 6.7734556;

                var ppos = new google.maps.LatLng(plat, plong);
                var mapOptions = {
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    //draggable: false,
                    zoom: 13,
                    center: ppos
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
                var request = {
                    location: ppos,
                    radius: 4000,
                    //keyword: 'restaurant+food',
                    type: 'food'
                    // key: 'MY_API_KEY makes no difference'
                };
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
                service.search(request, callback);
            };
        }
        function callback(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    createMarker(results[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        function createMarker(place) {
            var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: place.geometry.location,
                icon: place.icon
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.setContent("<b>" + place.name + "</b><br/>" + place.vicinity);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
        }

        function loadScript() {
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.type = "text/javascript";
            script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&callback=initializea";
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }

        window.onload = loadScript;
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initializeb()">
    <div id="search-panel">
        <input id="target" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    </div>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried variations on type/keyword, using restaurant and food. Results dont become either better or more frequent.

How to get more results?

(I want to give users a reasonable choice of places to eat, not just 4 for a city of 500k people (and 100s of restaurants, that google also knows and are returned for the maps search).)

Similar questions (with no helpful answers):

[Why do some results show up in Google Maps but not in Places API results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274768/why-do-some-results-show-up-in-google-maps-but-not-in-places-api-results)

[Different results in Google Places API and Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097952/different-results-in-google-places-api-and-google-maps)

[Different results in Google Places API and Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097952/different-results-in-google-places-api-and-google-maps)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230939/places-api-returning-fewer-results

Comment: @Mr/Mrs Downvoter: Please take the time to comment and enlighten me, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically: don't care about maps.google.com , when you work with the maps-API the API is relevant, almost everything is documented, and the documentation never guarantees to return all of something.

You run  a `nearbySearch`, which returns up to 20(with pagination 60) results, you can't get more results via a nearbySearch.

You may run a `radarSearch` instead which returns up to 200 results(but less details)

Comment: Thanks for answer!  I dont run into the 20 results issue, I get 5 results for a major city, 5km around city center, when searching for "restaurant".  Nothing guaranteed (like you write) makes sense, still, in this case (90%+ missing) it is not all that useful to me, when I want to offer users a choice in their area.

Comment: I see what you mean. I've noticed this before(see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159392/google-maps-places-autocomplete-missing-geometry/28160096 ), it seems to happen especially for germany(maybe because  of legal issues )

Comment: Thanks for link to bug report, I will accept this (unfortunately, since Google seems very slow recently to either acknowledge or fix bugs).